# Animate transitions between layouts

Tags: java, android, animation

I got 2 layouts (layout_1.xml and layout_2.xml) in my Project which I am switching with :

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_1);
```

and

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_2);
```

How can I make a animation which pushes the next layout from the left or right ?
Can someone help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want animation between activities, you can use [overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29),

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a viewswitcher, it'll allow you to add an animation easily.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html